# Sampling from a mixture of two Gamma distributions

Tags: r, skew, gamma-distribution, mixture

My intention was to generate samples from two mixed and heavily right-skewed Gamma distributions using the package called `bmixture`. Some examples are provided at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226834/sampling-from-a-mixture-of-two-gamma-distributions. For example, I can use the following, although the distributions are not really skewed (instead they seems normal).

```
library(bmixture)
set.seed(345)
nn <- 10000
wt <- c(0.85,0.20) #weight2
mu <- c(20,70)
sd <- c(1,1.2)
x <- rmixgamma(n=nn,weight=wt,alpha=mu,beta=sd) 
hist(x, breaks = 40, freq=FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

How can one possibly incorporate the skewness parameter? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: From your graph these distributions are skew.  The gamma distribution can be parameterised by its mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the parameters properly. `alpha` is the shape parameter, where lower values increase the skew (a shape of 1 gives the exponential distribution, and higher numbers tend towards a normal distribution), and `beta` is the rate parameter, where higher values lower the mean. (see *Characterization using shape α and rate β* [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution))

The mean of a gamma distribution is `alpha/beta`, and the standard deviation is `sqrt(alpha/beta^2)`. To get your target mean and standard deviations, you would need shape parameters of `c(400, 3402)` and rate parameters of `c(20, 48.61)`. These shape parameters would lead to distributions that would be impossible to distinguish from normal distributions at reasonable sample sizes.

To get positively skewed distributions, you need considerably lower `shape` parameters:

```r
library(bmixture)
set.seed(345)
nn <- 10000
wt <- c(0.80,0.20) 

shape <- c(3, 30)
rate <- shape / c(20, 70)

x <- rmixgamma(n = nn, weight = wt, alpha = shape, beta = rate) 

hist(x, breaks = 40, freq = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. One follow-up question: is that possible to have numbers generated from gamma distribution that are left-skewed?

Comment: @Gada no. The shape parameter must be non-negative, and the skew goes from extreme right-skew at 0 to no skew at infinity. I wonder if you are better trying a skewed normal distribution. I can add an example to demonstrate if you like

Comment: You can check out the `sn` package for generating skewed normal distributions.